# Simplify simple object clear function with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a `clear` function that accepts an `array`, `string`, or no arguments. If no arguments, it should clear the entire `data` object. It works fine, but looking for a code review.

The possibilities should be:

```
clear('one');
clear(); //clear all
clear(['one', 'three']);
```

```js
var data = {
  one: 'test1',
  two: 'test2',
  three: 'test3'
};

var clear = function(fields) {
  if (fields !== undefined) {
    if (typeof fields === 'string') {
      data[fields] = '';
    } else {
      _.each(fields, function(field) {
        if(data.hasOwnProperty(field)) {
          data[field] = '';
        }
      });
    }
  } else {
    // clear all
    _.each(data, function(value, key) {
      data[key] = '';
    });
  }
};

clear(['one', 'two']);
clear();
clear(['one']);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. The `clear` function relies on the global `data` variable. This could be more portable by passing the object in as the first argument, and then the fields as the second argument

   ```
   clear(data); // clear all
   clear(data, "one"); // clears the "one" field
   clear(data, ["one", "two"]); // clears multiple fields
   ```
2. Checking `if (fields !== undefined)` will accept `null` values as a field name. A "truthy" check is probably what you need:

   ```
   if (fields) {
     // ...
   } else {
     // ...
   }
   ```
3. What does "clear" mean? Your code assumes that all fields in an object should be cleared out to an empty string. What if the original value was a boolean, or number? Maybe you want to set that field to `null` instead. Better yet, maybe set it to `null` then delete the field:

   ```
   data[field] = null;
   delete data[field];
   ```

Other than that, it looks pretty good.